# How to save a data set in RMD file?

Tags: r, pdf, r-markdown, environment

I'm trying to `knit` a .rmd file into a pdf but I keep getting the following error:

> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos): Object not found.

I have a data set in my global environment that I read needs to be in my file, but I don't know how to import it.

Comment: When you knit a r-mardown file, it will run everything from a fresh environment. That is, any objects in your current environment that are not created in the r-markdown document will not be recognized, leading to the error.

Comment: You can save it with the function « save » to a « .RData » file and use the function « load »  to load this environment in your RMD afterwards